# Xamarin ios reachability not working

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, reachability

First I am new to Xamrain Mobile application Developer.

I added class reachability.cs inside ios mobile applictaion.
Now I want to check before or in between a service call, whether Internet is connect or not.
If mobile is not connected to internet it shows alertmessage "Please check the internet connection"  if mobile is connect to internet it process the service request.

How to check if connected to network or not?

```
  Reachability reachabilityObj = Reachability.InternetConnectionStatus ();
        if (reachabilityObj == false) {

            Console.WriteLine ("Not connect to Internet");
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine ("connect to Internet");

        }
```

Is this is correct way of implementing Reachability in xamarin for ios.

Please advice me if I am doing any thing wrong.

@All 
Thanks in advance

Comment: kiran, got any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The InternetConnectionStatus does not return a boolean but a status, so you should compare Reachability status:

```
Reachability reachabilityObj = Reachability.InternetConnectionStatus ();
if (reachabilityObj == NetworkStatus.NotReachable) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Not connect to Internet");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine ("connect to Internet");
}
```

Comment: @rckoeness if ( Reachability.InternetConnectionStatus () ==  NetworkStatus.NotReachable) {
Console.WriteLine ("Not connect to Internet");
} else {
Console.WriteLine ("connect to Internet");}    IT aways call to connect to Internet...  Even Wifi is on or Off.

Comment: Well that is how it should work, not sure if there could be an error in the mapping Obj-c to C#.

Comment: @kiran experiencing same problem here 2 years on. I believe it works in iOS9 however.